# Change stack order in mobile view at 1140 grid?

Tags: css, html, layout, mobile, fluid-layout

I want to implement the 1140grid at my site. The layout is pretty simple:

```
100% header
25% sidebar 75% page
100% footer
```

see also http://jsfiddle.net/KB5Nq/

the problem is that i would like to change the stack order when the site is in mobile view:

```
100% header
100% page
100% sidebar
100% footer
```

however, by default it arranges the blocks in the same order as they appear in the source code: header, sidebar, page, footer.

is there an easy css-only fix for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Reorder Main and Sidebar in the document flow and hack framework styles with negative margins:

```
.container .eightcol {margin-left:34.55% !important;}
.container .fourcol {margin-left:-100% !important;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KB5Nq/2/

Still, I woudn't recommend to use hacked framework that don't meet your needs in first place. For simple layouts sometimes it's faster to write clean and neat vanilla code.